# "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'" error on discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a bot for my Discord server using discord.py . I'm trying to make a command that gives a user a role named "Muted". But when I try and mute the user (by sending "0mute @user#0000"), I get errors.
My code for giving the role is this:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_any_role("Admin")
async def mute(ctx, user: discord.Member):
  await user.add_roles("Muted", atomic=False)
```

Note: I'm using regular discord.py, **NOT** discord.py rewrite.

Edit:
Recently found out I'm not allowed to post images of errors or code, as such I'll past the errors here as text instead of an image.

```
Ignoring exception in command mute:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 43, in mute
    await user.add_roles("Muted", atomic=False)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/member.py", line 669, in add_roles
    new_roles = utils._unique(Object(id=r.id) for s in (self.roles[1:], roles) for r in s)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/utils.py", line 287, in _unique
    return [x for x in iterable if not (x in seen or adder(x))]
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/utils.py", line 287, in <listcomp>
    return [x for x in iterable if not (x in seen or adder(x))]
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/member.py", line 669, in <genexpr>
    new_roles = utils._unique(Object(id=r.id) for s in (self.roles[1:], roles) for r in s)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Looks to me like [`user.add_roles()` takes a `Role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=role#discord.Member.add_roles), and you're giving it a string. My guess is that the library then tries to get the `id` attribute of that argument. Which would be fine if it were a `Role`, but not if it's a string. As you've provided.
Also, genuinely curious, how many people are in your class?

Comment: It looks like you will want to have a `Guild` object (representing the server), and then call `create_role` on it, to create a `Role`, which you can then give to users as you are trying to. That's what I've gathered from a quick look at the docs, at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Member.add_roles` takes `discord.Role` instances as the arguments, you're passing a string.

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role("Admin")
async def mute(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted") # Getting the role
    await user.add_roles(role, atomic=False)
```

Also the `pass_context` kwarg is not necessary in discord.py rewrite, the context is always passed

#### Reference:

- [`utils.get`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get)
- [`Member.add_roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles)

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked without issue. Thank you!!